# Created Date for Product2 not visible in custom report type

Tags: reporting, report-builder

Im wondering what's causing this.  I have 2 Custom Report Types.

One is:  Opportunities with Products

The other is: Products with Opportunities

In the former report type, I cannot see the field 'Product:Created Date' in the Report Builder, but I can in the latter.  Is this a limitation I'm not aware of - ie. if the Object is the Primary object for the report,then the date field can be filtered on, but not if it is the secondary object?
I have made sure that in the Custom Report Type builder the field is available for reporting.  But it's not visible in the Report Builder.

Is this perhaps because of the structure of Products & Opportunity Products, the junction object that relates opps & products together?  But I want to enable reporting of Opportunities that are linked to a Product with a certain Created Date.

Comment: Not sure if this is a limitation either, but have you tried setting up a custom formula field that points to the CreatedDate field in the Product2 object? Maybe this field appears for you in the report.

Comment: no I didn't.  That may be a viable workaround.  Let me try that.

Comment: To clairify:  Both report types are custom?  And in both report types youve added the appropriate Created Date field, but can't see them?  Or you can't add them either?

Comment: @HomerJ he said the field isn't visible in the Report Builder, so apparently he can see the fields outside the builder, but when trying to drag the field to the report, he doesn't find it in the list. Or at least that's what I understood.

Comment: Yes, Renato got it right, I can see both fields outside the report builder, and the latter report type can actually use the field as a filter, but the former report type cannot filter on it.

Comment: Are you trying to get the date when the product was created or the date it was added to a opportunity, or a date it was sold? Because in the first case you would really need to get the CreatedDate from Product2, but if you are trying to get a report on products related to opportunities, maybe you can find this in the OpportunityLineItem object. It contains a reference to the product too.

Comment: I'm trying to filter this based on the CreatedDate on the Product2 itself, ie when it was added to the database.  The business case for this is to see opps created with products added to them that match a certain creation date.

Comment: Try this: select the respective object from the "View" drop down field on the right side of the page. Click on the "Add fields related via lookup" link directly below the "View" drop down field. Select the appropriate link and subsequent fields. (source: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hithAAA)

Comment: Nope, doesn't show up there either.  I'm going to log a case to find out from Support whether this is some deliberate limitation or not.